# jQuery AJAX not receiving JSON from http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I ame using html with some jQuery to try out some JSON requests. I did a bit of research and tried making something small just to test it out. but when i run the script in my browser(Google Chrome) i dont get anything besides my html/css stuff. here is the code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        console.log("Test");
        console.log($.get("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/summoner/by-name/kerrie?api_key=[key]"));
    </script>
```

*[key] is my key from the api owners(not to be shared on the internet).

when i check the network tab it says "304, not modified" i dont if this has anything to do wit it.

I'm just starting with websites and JavaScript/jQuery any help would be helpfull.

Comment: This is not how to use `$.get`. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Randomly guessing is not a requirement.

Comment: The passed parameter api_key having string value '[key]'. Does key is an array value? Need to recheck as it is passing string.

Comment: [key] is just something i paste behind the url not a var, but i dont want my apikey spread over the internet so iput [key] on that spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding you can call ajax method as below

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.1/summoner/by-name/kerrie?api_key=[key]',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON',
async: false,
error: function(){},
success: function(resp){
         // resp variable will be your JSON responce
    }
}
```

});